# Time out issue causing increase in connections in weblogic

Tags: spring-integration

Facing increase in connections in web logic due to which application server goes down and needs to be restarted.

This happened due to threads waiting for response and recently added a fix to set `connectionTimeout` and `readTimeout` values to handle time out. But the fix has not resolved the problem

```
<beans:bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <beans:property name="readTimeout" value= "60000"/>
    <beans:property name="connectionTimeout" value= "60000"/>
</beans:bean>
```

I am using sprint-integration 3.0.8

Please find the stack trace below which is indicated in Thread dumps:

```
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-3" #62 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f18c353b800 nid=0x18dc waiting on condition [0x00007f18b35fa000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000006dfc36e28> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel.receive(MessagingTemplate.java:443)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel.receive(MessagingTemplate.java:436)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:343)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:367)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:315)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:225)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:204)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:286)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:277)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the stack trace like:

```
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:204)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:323)
```

gives me a clue for a typical mistake when someone invokes a flow without a reply, but wait for the return from gateway's method.

By default gateway's `receiveTimeout` is `-1` meaning [infinite wait](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-no-response).
Consider to use some valuable `default-reply-timeout` if there is no guaranty that your flow always return reply.

Out of topic. Also consider to upgrade to the latest [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/14/spring-integration-4-3-ga-is-available). `3.0.x` is out of support already.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Really appreciate it. It is working after setting the default-reply-timeout.